# interchanging sup and integral

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, solution-verification

I have the following question:

Let $f_n:[0,1]\to [0,\infty)$ be Lebesgue measurable and such that $f_n(x)\to 0$ for almost every $x$. Assume further that
\begin{equation}
\sup_n\int_0^1 g(f_n(x))dx\leq 1
\end{equation}
for some continuous $g:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ that satisfies $g(x)/x\to \infty$ as $x\to\infty$. Show that $\lim_{n}\int_0^1f_n(x)dx=0$.

My attempt: Since $f_n\to 0$ a.e., it suffices to show that we can interchange the limit and the integral in $\lim\int f_n(x)dx$. To that end, we seek $h(x)$ that is integrable and $|f(x)|\leq |h(x)|$ for a.e. $x$.

Since $g(x)/x\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$, there exists some $M>0$ such that for all $x\geq M$, $g(x)>x$. Define $h_n(x):[0,1]\to[0,\infty)$ to be a piecewise function such that:
\begin{equation}
h_n(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
M & \text{if $f_n(x)<M$,}\\
g(f_n(x)) & \text{if $f_n(x)\geq M$}.
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
Clearly, $|f_n(x)|\leq |h_n(x)|$ for every $n$. Our objective is now to find one $h(x)$ that works for all $n$, and this is where I am stuck.

To show integrability of each $h_n(x)$, we observe that
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
\int_0^1 h_n(x)dx
& = \int_{\{f_n(x)<M\}}Mdx+\int_{\{f_n(x)\geq M\}}g(f_n(x))dx\\
& \leq M + \int_0^1 g(f_n(x))dx \leq M+1
\end{split}\end{equation}

My guess is that to find one $h(x)$ that works for all $n$, we should take $\sup_n h_n(x)$, but then I don't know if
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 \sup_n h_n(x)dx =(?) \sup_n \int_0^1 h_n(x)dx.
\end{equation}

Any hint will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\epsilon>0$, find some $N>0$ such that 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{g(x)}{x}\geq\dfrac{1}{\epsilon},~~~~x\geq N,
\end{align*}
then
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}f_{n}(x)dx&=\int_{(f_{n}<N)}f_{n}(x)dx+\int_{(f_{n}\geq N)}f_{n}(x)dx.
\end{align*}
While, 
\begin{align*}
\int_{(f_{n}\geq N)}f_{n}(x)dx&=\int_{(f_{n}\geq N)}\dfrac{f_{n}(x)}{g(f_{n}(x))}\cdot g(f_{n}(x))dx\\
&\leq\int_{(f_{n}\geq N)}\epsilon\cdot g(f_{n}(x))dx\\
&\leq\epsilon\cdot\sup_{n}\int_{0}^{1}g(f_{n}(x))dx\\
&\leq\epsilon.
\end{align*}
On the other hand, since $f_{n}(x)\rightarrow 0$ a.e., by Egorov Theorem, we can find a measurable set $S$ such that $|S|<\epsilon/N$ such that $f_{n}\rightarrow 0$ uniformly on $[0,1]-S$. As a result,
\begin{align*}
\int_{(f_{n}<N)}f_{n}(x)dx&=\int_{(f_{n}<N)\cap S}f_{n}(x)dx+\int_{(f_{n}<N)\cap([0,1]-S)}f_{n}(x)dx\\
&\leq N\cdot|S|+\int_{[0,1]-S}f_{n}(x)dx\\
&\leq\epsilon+\int_{[0,1]-S}f_{n}(x)dx.
\end{align*}
The uniform convergence of $f_{n}$ on $[0,1]-S$ entails that
\begin{align*}
\int_{[0,1]-S}f_{n}(x)dx\rightarrow 0,
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f_{n}(x)dx\leq 2\epsilon.
\end{align*}
The arbitrariness of $\epsilon>0$ gives that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f_{n}(x)dx=0.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon >0$. Choose $M$ such that $\frac t {g(t)} <\epsilon $ for  $t >M$. Then $\int_{f_n >M} f_n(t)dt =\int_{f_n >M} g(f_n(t)) \frac {f_n(t)} {g(f_n(t))} dt<\epsilon \int_{f_n >M} g(f_n(t))dt \leq \epsilon$. Now apply DCT to $\int_{f_n \leq M} f_n(t)dt$.

I have assumed that $g>0$. If $g$ has zeros then we can replace $g$ by $\frac  {1+g} 2$. This function  satisfies the hypothesis and it is  strictly positive.